# Artificial neural network : Bug with GridSearchCV returns the first parameters each time

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am doing a ANN in Python and I am looking for the best parameters for my ANN with GridSearchCV (sklearn).
The problem is that each time, "best_parameters" attribute returns the first element of each parameter (so if I change the order of my elements, then the return is different).

Here is my code :

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 17:27].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Find best parameters
def build_classifier(optimizer):
    # Init ANN
    classifier = Sequential()
    # Add input and first hidden layers
    classifier.add(Dense(units=6, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform", input_dim=10))
    # Add another hidder layer
    classifier.add(Dense(units=6, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
    # Add output layer
    classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="uniform"))
    # Compile ANN
    classifier.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="mean_squared_error")
    return classifier

# Looking for best parameters with GridSearchCV
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_classifier)
parameters = {"batch_size":[1, 5, 10], "epochs":[100,200], "optimizer": ["rmsprop", "sgd", "adam"]}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_grid=parameters, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=10)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
best_precision = grid_search.best_score_
```

So in the line `parameters = {"batch_size":[1, 5, 10], "epochs":[100,200], "optimizer": ["rmsprop", "sgd", "adam"]}` I have the parameters I want to try, and the attribute "best_parameters" always returns the first element of each parameter (check the picture where I try several orders for the parameters).
[best_parameters return according to parameter order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EmTY.png)

I don't understand where this comes from and how to correct it.

Comment: I didn't find any solution and really need to correct this to be able to find the best parameters for my ANN... Please anybody help...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, which was a mistake I did...
I used KerasClassifier to find the best parameters, while I wanted to do regression... So I guess KerasClassifier didn't succeed to do what he had to do and then return the first parameters.
Since I am doing regression, I have to use KerasRegressor instead.